# How to print keys and values of a dictionary which is contained in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0,97.0,75.0,92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0,40.0,94.0],
    "tests": [75.0,90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

students=[lloyd,alice,tyler]
```

The given above is my python code.
I want to print out all the data in the students list, just like  the below example.

```
  Lloyd
[90, 97, 75, 92]
[88, 40, 94]
[75, 90]
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Actually I am trying to learn python from a site called Codeacademy. They presented me with this question. I tried a lot to get the output printed. But its not giving me any output which is closer to the actual required output

Comment: Others have asked the same question (with various degrees of own effort) here on Stack Overflow before. Did you search for other questions on this problem yet? We do ask that you at least share what you tried here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "For each" is to easy use on python:

Example:

```
items = [1,2,3,4]
for item in items:
    print item
```

This print all the numbers in our list

Here a solution:

```
for student in students:
    print "  ",student['name']
    print student['homework']
    print student['quizzes']
    print student['tests']
```

I hope this help you!

Answer (score 2):

```
lloyd = {"name": "Lloyd",
         "homework": [90.0,97.0,75.0,92.0],
         "quizzes": [88.0,40.0,94.0],
         "tests": [75.0,90.0]}

alice = {"name": "Alice",
         "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
         "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
         "tests": [89.0, 97.0]}

tyler = {"name": "Tyler",
         "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
         "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
         "tests": [100.0, 100.0]}

students=[lloyd, alice, tyler]

for s in students:
    print s["name"]
    print s["homework"]
    print s["quizzes"]
    print s["tests"]
```

If you want to format a line (fancy):

```
>>>print "{:>10}".format("Lloyd")
```

would print

```
      Lloyd
```